# How do you define InputExample in Google Bert sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, bert-language-model

I am trying to run the example Google Bert code from this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/sentiment-analysis-in-10-minutes-with-bert-and-hugging-face-294e8a04b671 to get an understanding of how it works before I try to run sentiment analysis on my own csv files.

I am getting this error though when I try to run the code: NameError: name 'InputExample' is not defined

Does anyone know how to fix this code?

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil


URL = "https://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz"

dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file(fname="aclImdb_v1.tar.gz", 
                                  origin=URL,
                                  untar=True,
                                  cache_dir='.',
                                  cache_subdir='')


# Create main directory path ("/aclImdb")
main_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), 'aclImdb')
# Create sub directory path ("/aclImdb/train")
train_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, 'train')
# Remove unsup folder since this is a supervised learning task
remove_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'unsup')
shutil.rmtree(remove_dir)
# View the final train folder
print(os.listdir(train_dir))

# We create a training dataset and a validation 
# dataset from our "aclImdb/train" directory with a 80/20 split.
train = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', batch_size=30000, validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', seed=123)
test = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', batch_size=30000, validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='validation', seed=123)

for i in train.take(1):
  train_feat = i[0].numpy()
  train_lab = i[1].numpy()

train = pd.DataFrame([train_feat, train_lab]).T
train.columns = ['DATA_COLUMN', 'LABEL_COLUMN']
train['DATA_COLUMN'] = train['DATA_COLUMN'].str.decode("utf-8")
train.head()


for j in test.take(1):
  test_feat = j[0].numpy()
  test_lab = j[1].numpy()

test = pd.DataFrame([test_feat, test_lab]).T
test.columns = ['DATA_COLUMN', 'LABEL_COLUMN']
test['DATA_COLUMN'] = test['DATA_COLUMN'].str.decode("utf-8")
test.head()


InputExample(guid=None,
             text_a = "Hello, world",
             text_b = None,
             label = 1)



def convert_data_to_examples(train, test, DATA_COLUMN, LABEL_COLUMN): 
  train_InputExamples = train.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this case
                                                          text_a = x[DATA_COLUMN], 
                                                          text_b = None,
                                                          label = x[LABEL_COLUMN]), axis = 1)

  validation_InputExamples = test.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this case
                                                          text_a = x[DATA_COLUMN], 
                                                          text_b = None,
                                                          label = x[LABEL_COLUMN]), axis = 1)
  
  return train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples

  train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples = convert_data_to_examples(train, 
                                                                           test, 
                                                                           'DATA_COLUMN', 
                                                                           'LABEL_COLUMN')
  
def convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(examples, tokenizer, max_length=128):
    features = [] # -> will hold InputFeatures to be converted later

    for e in examples:
        # Documentation is really strong for this method, so please take a look at it
        input_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            e.text_a,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=max_length, # truncates if len(s) > max_length
            return_token_type_ids=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            pad_to_max_length=True, # pads to the right by default # CHECK THIS for pad_to_max_length
            truncation=True
        )

        input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask = (input_dict["input_ids"],
            input_dict["token_type_ids"], input_dict['attention_mask'])

        features.append(
            InputFeatures(
                input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, label=e.label
            )
        )

    def gen():
        for f in features:
            yield (
                {
                    "input_ids": f.input_ids,
                    "attention_mask": f.attention_mask,
                    "token_type_ids": f.token_type_ids,
                },
                f.label,
            )

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen,
        ({"input_ids": tf.int32, "attention_mask": tf.int32, "token_type_ids": tf.int32}, tf.int64),
        (
            {
                "input_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                "attention_mask": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                "token_type_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
            },
            tf.TensorShape([]),
        ),
    )


DATA_COLUMN = 'DATA_COLUMN'
LABEL_COLUMN = 'LABEL_COLUMN'

train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples = convert_data_to_examples(train, test, DATA_COLUMN, LABEL_COLUMN)

train_data = convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(list(train_InputExamples), tokenizer)
train_data = train_data.shuffle(100).batch(32).repeat(2)

validation_data = convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(list(validation_InputExamples), tokenizer)
validation_data = validation_data.batch(32)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')])

model.fit(train_data, epochs=2, validation_data=validation_data)

pred_sentences = ['This was an awesome movie. I watch it twice my time watching this beautiful movie if I have known it was this good',
                  'One of the worst movies of all time. I cannot believe I wasted two hours of my life for this movie']

tf_batch = tokenizer(pred_sentences, max_length=128, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='tf')
tf_outputs = model(tf_batch)
tf_predictions = tf.nn.softmax(tf_outputs[0], axis=-1)
labels = ['Negative','Positive']
label = tf.argmax(tf_predictions, axis=1)
label = label.numpy()
for i in range(len(pred_sentences)):
  print(pred_sentences[i], ": \n", labels[label[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from transformers import InputExample
```

is missing